# Win 7 - Run wifi and cable connection simultaneously

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I'm wondering how I can connect to 2 different networks (one WiFi and one by ethernet cable). I have notebook with built-in Wireless adapter and also ethernet adapter. After i plug in the ethernet cable, my WiFi is automatically disabled/shutdown. I tried to look to in both adapter properteries but none of them has any options saying to disable the other connection.

I would appreciate any tips that would help.

Thanks

EDIT: I'm trying to be able to search for WiFi networks (and be able to connect to them) while I'm connected to the Internet with my cable connection. I'm not trying to use both connections for internet. I just want to be connected to Internet while I inspect WiFi networks.

I think it's silly that I have to unplug/plug ethernet cable everytime I wanna see the WiFi networks signal strength/search on the internet.

Comment: Try looking in the BIOS. Sometimes there is an option for that.

Comment: I just checked BIOS and there is nothing that would help. Any other tips?

Comment: Can you expand on what it is that you're trying to do?

Comment: rriower is right, what do you want to do? Why not just use one network? Even if you get the WiFi/Ethernet thing to work, it might be tricky to join two networks at the same time. http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/220875-connecting-two-networks-simultaneously.html & http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/308396-connect-2-wireless-networks-simultaneously.html

Comment: I edited my post explaining what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that.

In Windows and Unix (but **not** in Linux) you can have only one routing table, *i.e.*, a set of instructions which specify how other pcs can be reached. Any routing table allows *one* and *only one* default gateway, and the interface through which the default gateway can be reached *must* be uniquely specified.

Thus, when you connect through the cable, you are not really disconnected from the wifi: the only thing that now happens is that the rule specifying the default gateway for the wifi is replaced by the default rule for the cable connection. The rules to reach the LAN pcs through the wireless interface remain in place: the command

```
  route print -4
```

will show you that rule to be still there.

In line of principle, once you disconnect the cable, the routing table should be automatically modified to allow reaching the wireless gateway, whatever that is. If this does not occur, reconnecting through the wireless interface will re-establish full connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for response. I would mark your post as answer but do you have any reference?

Comment: @e_scape Sure: read this Technet page, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779122%28v=ws.10%29.aspx, especially where it says, in the Notes:**When you configure a default gateway on each network adapter, you create a 0.0.0.0 route for each network adapter. However, only one default route is actually used**, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. After some studying I found out that what I want is possible with multihoming when you have to set default gateway only for 1 network and use static routing for the other. But this method is really complicated and I dont think this will work with networks with DHCP servers (like 99% of them).